# How to reproduce the Stock Battery Icon

Tags: java, android

im new to these things. How can I make a java file for android in which it will function like the stock kitkat battery indicator that shows each battery level via individual images and charging discharging states. Step by step if you could. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Step : Create Assets, 5 or 10 different images should work fine.
2. Step : Create a function that gets your battery level
3. Step : Create a procedure that shows one of these battery icons according to the current powerlevel.

The java code shouldn't be that complicated at all...

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

// Are we charging / charged?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                 status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

// How are we charging?
int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

to determine the power level simply use

```
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

( source: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html )

these should be everything you need except basic java knowledge.
hope that helped you a little ;)

i did this myself a few ago and the hardest part is creating assets that look nice :P

Comment: how can I get the level? int level = batteryStatus .getIntExtra ( BatteryManager. EXTRA_LEVEL , - 1);
int scale = batteryStatus .getIntExtra ( BatteryManager. EXTRA_SCALE , - 1);
float batteryPct = level / ( float ) scale; like that? where would I put it master? Im such a noob

Comment: exactly, this will give you a percentage between 0 and 100, you can then try to put this into many IF-Cases like If (batteryPct > 80) else If (batteryPct > 60)  etc. etc... You will have to declare a function that will return you batteryPct, or you declare it as a global variable, but that should be known already. you can easily start with a label instead of assets, just write the current batteryPct into the Label for debugging reasons. You can exchange this with graphics later.

Comment: i have now the level. but it displays text only. what to do next?

Comment: well you will have to change the method so it will display a picture instead ;) you will have to make 5 or 10 pictures and add them to your R.drawable , i think people on your other question told you how to do that ... (he assumed you will use 10 pictures) you will have to create NinePatch Files, easiest way to do so is to use the google generator : https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg-history/9472134d092f3375aa9cf767d6a4b2eca561c0ba/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html you will have to add them into your project and make one of those pictures to be displayed instead of the string.